# inherit profile based property in maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, module, pom.xml, profile, platform

I have parent maven pom.xml like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>mygroup-sharing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>linux</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
                <property>
                    <name>platform.suffix</name>
                    <value>linux-i386</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>solaris-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>solaris</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
                <property>
                    <name>platform.suffix</name>
                    <value>solaris-i386</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        ...
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <depr.version>3.6.1-${platform.suffix}</depr.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

and I have child (and I will have more) pom in subdirectory:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>mygroup-submodule</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>mygroup-sharing</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>

    ...

    <dependencies>
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>depr</artifactId>
            <version>${depr.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The problem is, that the version is badly used when trying to compile the child project:

```
Downloading: http://myserver/nexus/content/groups/public//mygroup/depr/3.6.1-${platform.suffix}/depr-3.6.1-${platform.suffix}.pom
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) mygroup:depr:jar:3.6.1-${platform.suffix}

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=mygroup -DartifactId=depr -Dversion=3.6.1-${platform.suffix} -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=mygroup -DartifactId=depr -Dversion=3.6.1-${platform.suffix} -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
        1) mygroup:mygroup-submodule:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) mygroup:depr:jar:3.6.1-${platform.suffix}

----------
....
```

... so as you can see, the property platform.suffix is badly applied when using the parent pom.

Also there's warning when running `mvn -X install`
    [WARNING] Overriding profile: 'linux-i386' (source: pom) with new instance from source: pom
but there's no definition of profiles in the child pom file.

If I use this in each pom.xml file, it works properly. But I don't want to have copy-pasted this long part of pom.xml as it also can be extended (with more platforms).

Is there any other way how to share this type (platform suffix) configuration across other modules ?

Comment: Is this a multi module build? Apart from that why do you need such thing? Are we are talking about Java ? Doesn't look like.

Comment: Furthermore a thing is comming into my mind. Why changing the version instead of the classifier?

Comment: Try `mvn help:active-profiles` to see which profiles are currently active. It may be that yours simply aren't being selected for some odd reason.

Comment: I don't plan it like multi-module build, but it can be. It is java, but the projec "depr" is platform dependant (JNI etc.)

Comment: the `mvn help:active-profiles` only shows the profile specified in  `settings.xml` (company nexus repos definition)

Comment: when using `mvn -X install` there is a warning:
`[WARNING] Overriding profile: 'linux-i386' (source: pom) with new instance from source: pom`
but there's no definition of profiles in the child pom